# i have json response but its optional can any one tell me how to unwrap optional json

Tags: ios, json, swift

please tell me how to unwrap this josn response because of optional json i am not able to parse in label

i have tried my best but  i am new to swift so i can't get it to unwrap the optional json
response::

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600000848340>(
{
    contributors = "";
    coordinates = "";
    "created_at" = "Thu Jul 12 11:49:57 +0000 2018";
    entities =     {
        hashtags =         (
        );
        media =         (
                        {
                "display_url" = "pic.twitter.com/IJtq6aLM7K";
                "expanded_url" = "";
                id = 1017375504448479232;
                "id_str" = 1017375504448479232;
                indices =                 (
                    12,
                    35
                );
                "media_url" = "";
                "media_url_https" = "";
                sizes =                 {
                    large =                     {
                        h = 1820;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 2048;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        h = 1067;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 1200;
                    };
                    small =                     {
                        h = 604;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 680;
                    };
                    thumb =                     {
                        h = 150;
                        resize = crop;
                        w = 150;
                    };
                };
                type = photo;
                url = "";
            }
        );
        symbols =         (
        );
        urls =         (
        );
        "user_mentions" =         (
        );
    };
    "extended_entities" =     {
        media =         (
                        {
                "display_url" = "pic.twitter.com/IJtq6aLM7K";
                "expanded_url" = "";
                id = 1017375504448479232;
                "id_str" = 1017375504448479232;
                indices =                 (
                    12,
                    35
                );
                "media_url" = "";
                "media_url_https" = "";
                sizes =                 {
                    large =                     {
                        h = 1820;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 2048;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        h = 1067;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 1200;
                    };
                    small =                     {
                        h = 604;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 680;
                    };
                    thumb =                     {
                        h = 150;
                        resize = crop;
                        w = 150;
                    };
                };
                type = photo;
                url = "";
            }
        );
    };
    "favorite_count" = 0;
    favorited = 0;
    geo = "";
    id = 1017375507174719488;
    "id_str" = 1017375507174719488;
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "";
    "in_reply_to_status_id" = "";
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "";
    "in_reply_to_user_id" = "";
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "";
    "is_quote_status" = 0;
    lang = fr;
    place = "";
    "possibly_sensitive" = 0;
    "retweet_count" = 0;
    retweeted = 0;
    source = "";
    text = "Tweet Tweet ";
    truncated = 0;
    user =     {
        "contributors_enabled" = 0;
        "created_at" = "Tue Mar 27 05:14:33 +0000 2018";
        "default_profile" = 1;
        "default_profile_image" = 0;
        description = "";
        entities =         {
            description =             {
                urls =                 (
                );
            };
        };
        "favourites_count" = 3;
        "follow_request_sent" = 0;
        "followers_count" = 1;
        following = 0;
        "friends_count" = 0;
        "geo_enabled" = 1;
        "has_extended_profile" = 0;
        id = 978500498897563648;
        "id_str" = 978500498897563648;
        "is_translation_enabled" = 0;
        "is_translator" = 0;
        lang = en;
        "listed_count" = 0;
        location = "";
        name = Mike;
        notifications = 0;
        "profile_background_color" = F5F8FA;
        "profile_background_image_url" = "";
        "profile_background_image_url_https" = "";
        "profile_background_tile" = 0;
        "profile_image_url" = "";
        "profile_image_url_https" = "";
        "profile_link_color" = 1DA1F2;
        "profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
        "profile_text_color" = 333333;
        "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
        protected = 0;
        "screen_name" = Mike50430315;
        "statuses_count" = 13;
        "time_zone" = "";
        "translator_type" = none;
        url = "";
        "utc_offset" = "";
        verified = 0;
    };
}
```

because of this i am getting nil value in all like name text retweet please tell me how to solve this

```
 var timeline = (FHSTwitterEngine.shared().getTimelineForUser(FHSTwitterEngine.shared().authenticatedUsername, isID: true, count: 10), terminator: "")
```

from this line i am getting whole response

and then i have on array i create and store in to array like below

```
var serviceData = [AnyObject]()
let timelinedata = [timeline] as [AnyObject]
serviceData = (timelinedata)
print(serviceData)
```

Comment: In swift you should use "Any" rather than "AnyObject".  Also, it seems that your JSON is a dictionary not an array.   Have you tried: print(timeline)

Comment: yes i tried to print timeline but still i am getting optinal

Comment: what about? if let validTimeline = timeline { print(validTimeline) }

Comment: if i implement this then first i am getting error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(Any!, terminator: String)'" like this

Comment: @ekscrypto please help me to solve this where is the issue i can't get it

Comment: See Edit 2 in my answer

Comment: its not working i tried this earlier

Comment: Last try for me, updated my answer once again. Follow the links to get more help as this is obviously something specific to the answer type you get from FHSTwitterEngine

Answer (score 0):

In general, anything optional can be unwrapped like so:

```
let optionalValue: String? = "Hello, this is optional!"

if let noLongerOptional = optionalValue {
    print("\(noLongerOptional) no its not! ahah")
}
```

---

Edit: more specific example...

Assuming you have a variable 'myJson' which hold your optional value... and you did:

```
print("\(myJson)")
```

You can solve this by:

```
if let validJson = myJson {
  print("\(validJson)")
}
```

---

Edit 2: ... FHSTwitter... (updated.... this is getting long)

```
let twitterEngine = FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine()
let twitterUser = twitterEngine.authenticatedID
let timeline = twitterEngine.getTimelineForUser(twitterUser, isID: true, count: 10)
```

According to FHSTwitterEngine docs... getTimelineForUser() will return either a NSError or an array of Tweets.

so...

```
if let error = timeline as? Error {
  print("Oops, looks like something went wrong: \(error)")
} else {
  if let tweets = timeline as? [Any] {
    for tweet in tweets {
       print("This is a tweet: \(tweet)")
    }
  }
}
```

If you have any more trouble using FHSTwitterEngine, I suggest you play with: https://github.com/natesymer/FHSTwitterEngine/tree/master/FHSTwitterEngineDemoSwift/Demo-Swift

Or open a support ticket with the FHSTwitterEngine developer(s) at: https://github.com/natesymer/FHSTwitterEngine/issues

Good Luck!

Comment: but can you please tel me how to unwrap json that i given

Comment: Yes thnaks i wil implement it

Comment: please tell me why "[(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Any>.some(<__NSArrayM 0x600000856e00>" is coming i am implement ur suggestion still i am facing issue

Comment: @Vishal can't help you further without showing the code that receives/create the Json variable and the code using the variable.  The Json itself is irrelevant.

Comment: please check my code and tell me where i am doing wrong